# Unsure of what this tube is on wired motor

Tags: motor, identification

Upon looking for an answer online I found none, maybe it was the way I was describing it I don't know, on to the point though. On VEX robotics motors there is a tube with the wire looped in through it, here is a picture

[image]

It is covered with heat shrink tubing I believe and the inside of it is some sort of metal/ceramic that is more brittle. Maybe it's some sort of resistor because I think the materials of the inside of the resistor and tube are the same. Also there is no tag for Electric Motor yet, maybe should be added for those with 300 rep.

Comment: is it one of these? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead

Answer (score 2):

It is a ferrite ring to reduce interference from the motor interfering with either the receiver or processor controlling the motor.

Looping the wire through the ferrite ring creates some inductance that provides a low-pass filter.

You will often see the same thing on notebook computer power supplies.